# Unable to connect to the remote server from Windows service

Tags: windows, service, connect

When I try to connect to remote server from a .Net windows service installed on the local machine, it is working correctly, but when install the windows service in the same server where the web application is installed, it gives this error:

```
"Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote server from the Windows Service?  Is there a firewall that could be blocking the connection?  Could there be issues with a router preventing the connection?

Comment: What account is the service running as? The default service accounts have extremely limited access to other systems.

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote server from the Windows Service? 
I am trying to push data to remote server using websync.

 Is there a firewall that could be blocking the connection?
Ans No, because when I am running windows service from local system then it is able to connect remote server and not giving any error.

 Could there be issues with a router preventing the connection? –
How can router prevent connection. What is the solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for this.
But this is a guessing game with multiple combinations of choices and paths since you did not describe the context well (which Windows, editions and versions, etc.).

One of the possible reasons is "Loopback check" security feature in Windows:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861